# How to change the levels of a factor variable conditioned on another variable in R?

Tags: r

## Data

I have a large data set with more than million rows. Following is a sample from original data set:

```
> dput(dg)
structure(list(Vehicle.ID = c(1324L, 1582L, 401L, 811L, 2429L, 
2523L, 1033L, 2039L, 1662L, 1288L, 1742L, 74L, 2607L, 304L, 2476L, 
127L, 2484L, 395L, 2793L, 1618L, 2395L, 270L, 2192L, 354L, 2234L, 
766L, 447L, 2132L, 1848L, 532L, 2113L, 2905L, 1166L, 1452L, 2701L, 
2144L, 2202L, 955L, 1500L, 2572L, 1234L, 2113L, 576L, 997L, 891L, 
335L, 1156L, 2480L, 1980L, 2798L), Link.number = c(2L, 10000L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L
), Lane = structure(c(4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Vehicle.ID", "Link.number", 
"Lane"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(590084L, 734964L, 
198436L, 375206L, 1124080L, 1235905L, 454260L, 1000231L, 736019L, 
558048L, 831494L, 38723L, 1191084L, 121339L, 1169687L, 61487L, 
1176256L, 150989L, 1292775L, 749442L, 1148838L, 124741L, 1037887L, 
156697L, 1056299L, 325099L, 243937L, 1000026L, 881043L, 231402L, 
991321L, 1349675L, 510814L, 691971L, 1255936L, 1038333L, 1055881L, 
411274L, 671564L, 1225808L, 580627L, 1012699L, 238513L, 432055L, 
413181L, 118829L, 514324L, 1212860L, 910530L, 1299547L))
```

## Goal

The 'Lane' variable in `dg` is integer variable and it has following unique values based on the variable 'Link.number':

```
> ddply(dg, .(Link.number), summarize, unique.lanes = list(unique(Lane)))
  Link.number     unique.lanes
1           1    5, 4, 1, 2, 3
2           2 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6
3           3    2, 1, 4, 5, 3
4       10000                1
```

Please note that the 'unique.lanes' in case of each 'Lane.number' are different from other cases. For example, a unique lane 1 for link number 1 is not the same as the unique lane 1 for link number 10000.
My goal is to change these unique values. So, I converted the `Lane` variable to factor and now 'dg' contains Lane as a factor. I want to change these levels to new values by reversing their order as below:

```
    Link.number     old Lane level   new Lane level
           1            1               5
           1            2               4
           1            3               3
           1            4               2
           1            5               1

           2            1               6
           2            2               5
           2            3               4
           2            4               3
           2            5               2
           2            6               1

           3            1               5
           3            2               4
           3            3               3
           3            4               2
           3            5               1   

       10000            1               7
```

## Problem

After converting `Lane` to factor, if I look at its levels, I get:

```
> ddply(dg, .(Link.number), summarize, lev = list(levels(Lane)))
  Link.number              lev
1           1 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
2           2 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
3           3 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
4       10000 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Link.number 10000 only has one unique value i.e. 1 but it gives the levels as 1:6. How can I change the levels conditioned on Link.number?

Comment: How do you determine the numbering of the new levels? Why (for Link.number 10000) does 1 become 7 but (for Link.number 2) 1 becomes 6?

Comment: Here is how: the lane numbers in the data frame were assigned by the software in which the simulation of traffic was run. But actually the lane numbers are different and I know which lane number should be replaced by what. There is nothing in the data which could be used in the code to define new levels.

Comment: So...how do you expect someone to generate a solution to this problem other than simply manually entering the correct factor labels?

Comment: I don't know how can I manually give different levels for a link.number. Is ifelse the only way?

Comment: It sounds like you should either attach a letter or additional number if you want the lane levels. But if each lane value is totally unrelated to any other from a different link, why are they in the same column of the table? It's as though you have apples, oranges, and grapes in the apples column.

Comment: Unfortunately that is the output of the software in which I run simulation